# How do I keep the substring function from stripping non-latin characters from an existing variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I'm trying to update a script so that it doesn't strip out (or change) non-latin characters from a variable when pulling a substring of the variable.

For example, take these queries:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var = 'δtest'
-- Query 1:
select N'ABC' + substring(@var,1,len(@var))
-- Query 2:
select N'ABC' + substring(CAST(@var as NVARCHAR(MAX)),1,len(@var))
-- Query 3:
select N'ABC' + substring(N'δtest',1,5)
```

In query 3, I can successfully prevent it from converting the 'δ' to a 'd' by adding the N prefix to the string. However, when declare the variable as an nvarchar, presumably doing the same thing that the N prefix is supposed to do, the substring converts the 'δ' to a d.

As can be seen in Query 2, I tried casting the variable within the substring function to see if that would force it to view the variable as an nvarchar datatype but that didn't work. Any other options people recommend trying?

Edit:

The above was an extremely simplified version of what I'm working with and was hoping to find a way to force the SUBSTRING function to do this. In response to the answer from ram933, here's what I'm working with in the script itself:

```
INSERT INTO @SQLTbl
  (tablename,
  whereclause)
SELECT SCh.NAME + '.[' + ST.NAME + ']',
  (SELECT '[' + SC.NAME + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr
    + ''' OR ' + Char(10)
  FROM sys.columns SC
  JOIN sys.types STy
    ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id
    AND STy.user_type_id = SC.user_type_id
  WHERE STY.NAME IN ( 'varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar' )
    AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id
  ORDER BY SC.NAME
  FOR xml path(''))
FROM sys.tables ST
JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls
  ON chktbls.tablename = ST.NAME
JOIN sys.schemas SCh
  ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id
WHERE ST.NAME <> 'SearchTMP'
GROUP BY ST.object_id,
  SCh.NAME + '.[' + ST.NAME + ']';

UPDATE @SQLTbl
SET sqlstatement = 'SELECT * INTO SearchTMP FROM ' + tablename
  + ' WHERE '
  + Substring(whereclause, 1, Len(whereclause)-5)
```

That nested select query is generating the string that has the δ character in it. I'm not sure of a good way to add the unicode prefix to that.

To head off any commentary about non-latin characters in column names, the 'δ' came from customer data and I'm just trying to work out a way to get around that should I encounter similar weird choices from customers in the future.

Edit 2:
The nested select query:

```
  (SELECT '[' + SC.NAME + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr
    + ''' OR ' + Char(10)
  FROM sys.columns SC
  JOIN sys.types STy
    ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id
    AND STy.user_type_id = SC.user_type_id
  WHERE STY.NAME IN ( 'varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar' )
    AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id
  ORDER BY SC.NAME
  FOR xml path(''))
```

It is looking at the sys.columns table and generating results that look like the below code block from the column names:

```
[COLUMN1] LIKE '@searchstring' OR
...
```

And then using the `FOR XML PATH('')` statement to convert those results into a string that is then inserted into the whereclause column. The output from it appears to be an nvarchar datatype because when I select that column from @SQLTbl it maintains the δ character. It only changes once I've taken the substring.

Here's the definition for the @SQLTbl table:

```
DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE
(
  tablename    SYSNAME,
  whereclause  NVARCHAR(max),
  sqlstatement NVARCHAR(max),
  execstatus   BIT
)
```

Comment: The answer was from @ram933 - not me - good example of why not to oversimplify a question.

Comment: And its not clear to me which sub-query or which column contains this data. But the answer is going to be similar, ensure everything is nvarchar.

Comment: What is the definition of @SQLTbl? The columns will need to be `nvarchar`

Comment: They are.     
DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE
      (
         tablename    SYSNAME,
         whereclause  NVARCHAR(max),
         sqlstatement NVARCHAR(max),
         execstatus   BIT
      )

Answer (score 1):

```
set @var = N'δtest'
```

should fix it for you.